# Unable to match final part of String using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that is a list of website names followed by a delimiter and then the url, with each name/url pair followed by a space and set of new line delimiters. Unfortunately the new line delimiters are not always present, there is a space between each pair, but as the site names can have spaces I can't simply split on space.

I have a regex and (according to regexPlanet) it matches all but the last pair.

Is it possible to get the last pair also?

Regex:
`(.+?(?=\|)).(.+?(?= ))`

Example String:
`Website 1|https://site1.example.com \r\nWeb Site 2|https://2.example.co.uk \r\nSite 3|https://w3.example.com.au site 4|https://s4.example.org \r\nWeb Site5|https://s5.other.example.ac.uk/`

RegexPlanet reports that the regex will match on the first four sites, just not for the fifth one.

Any ideas would be greatly welcomed

Comment: You may try [`([^|]+)\|(.+?(?=\s|\z))`](https://regex101.com/r/8LuYU0/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 capture groups:

```
([^|]+)\|(.+?(?=\s|\z))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8LuYU0/1)

**Regex Details:**

- `([^|]+)`: Capture group #1 to match 1+ of any character that is not `|`
- `\|`: Match a literal `|`
- `(.+?(?=\s|\z))`: Capture group #2 to match 1+ of any character that is followed by a whitespace or end of line

Comment: As both answers would answer my question, this one improves the regex I had and explains the regex.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just added `|$` to end of the regex

```
(.+?(?=\|)).(.+?(?= |$))
```